# How can I extend the public methods in a plugin with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-1.9

How can I extend the public methods in a plugin with jquery?

```
$.fn.myPluginName = function(PublicOptions) {

    // Remember the root assigned object.
    var Root = this;

    // Set private defaults.
    var Defaults = {
        param1:       'param1',
        param2:       'param2',
        onSuccess:    function(){}
    };

    // Do a deep copy of the options - http://goo.gl/gOSSrg
    var Options = $.extend(true, {}, Defaults, PublicOptions);

    // Private debug function.
    function log(msg) {
        console.debug(msg);
    }

    // Define the public api and its public methods.
    var PublicApi = {

        method1 : function (PublicOptions) {

            return "extended method 1";
        },
        method2 : function (PublicOptions) {

            return "extended method 2";
        }
    };

    // Return the PublicApi object.
    return PublicApi;
};
```

The extended methods that I want to put them inside `var PublicApi = {}`

```
var extensionMethods = {

   method3: function(){
       return "extended method 3";
   },

   method4: function(){
       return "extended method 4";
   }
};
```

Currently, for `console.log($(this).myPluginName());`,

```
Object {method1=function(), method2=function()}
```

But it would be ideal if I can extend the methods to,

```
Object {method1=function(), method2=function(), method3=function(), method3=function()}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, just add `method3` and `method4` as properties of `PublicApi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass the object to the plugin with slight modification of code like

```
$.fn.myPluginName = function(extMethods){
    //(...) Some code here
    PluginApi = { ... }   // your default methods go here
    if(typeof extMethods == "object"){
       for(var key in extMethods)
           PluginApi[key] = extMethods[key];
    }
}
```

What `if` block does is, it checks if the provided argument is an object and then adds the methods to `PluginApi` by the name of the property using `for...in` loop.

You can call like `$(this).myPluginName(extensionMethods);`

Comment: @tealou glad to have helped you :)

Comment: oh where does the `k` come from??

Comment: @tealou sorry.. that was a typo, which Alexander fixed. Check it now. Thanks Alex by the way!